# DOMDocument PHP web scraping

Tags: php, web-scraping, domdocument

I was wondering if there was any way to use dom to select elements that have dynamic tags. All of the tags start with link_(some id).

Example:

```
<tr id="link_111111">something in here...</tr>

<tr id="link_222222">something in here...</tr>

<tr id="link_333333">something in here...</tr>

<tr id="link_444444">something in here...</tr>

<tr id="link_555555">something in here...</tr>
```

I was wondering if I could grab all the tr's that have the id with link_ because I don't have the specific id's, they are random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an XPath expression to achieve this:

```
//tr[starts-with(@id, "link")]
```

Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('///tr[starts-with(@id, "link")]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    // Do whatever
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/149206)

Comment: @AmalMurali, If id contains `Link` in the upper case then your code won't work ;)

Answer (score 1):

DOM way using some string functions ...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html); $tagK = 'link_';
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tag) {
    if (substr(strtolower($tag->getAttribute('id')),0,strlen($tagK))===$tagK) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('id').PHP_EOL; 
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/149229)</kbd>

Comment: Just a note: This will match items even when the attribute value does not begin with `link`, for example: `foo_link_555555` will be matched.

Comment: The original version was right, except it had to use `=== 0` instead. I edited the answer, btw. Feel free to rollback if you wish. :P

Comment: @AmalMurali, Yeah I have to rollback as I had written for a generalized order. :) Sorry :) As the OP can adjust the id accordingly from the `$tagK`

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to have more flexible way and easy to Web Scrape.. I suggest you take a look at
https://github.com/fabpot/goutte which act as wrapper. that you can also used for clicking a link or submitting a form..

I made some tutorials using Goutte Class for Web Scraping.. Feel free to check it.
http://iapdesign.com/webdev/laravel-4-webdev/superb-web-scraping-tutorials-using-laravel-4/